# Set of vectors ordered by vector size allowing same size

Tags: c++, vector, set, compare

I have the following structure:

```
 auto comp = [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) -> bool
    { return a.size() < b.size(); };
    auto path = std::set <vector<int>, decltype(comp)> (comp);
```

When I now insert via

```
path.insert(vector<int>{g.id(v)});
```

He inserts of size 1 only 1, of size 2 only 1 etc.

I want him ordered by the size, but he should compare really the vectors to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but try the following:

```
auto comp = [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) -> bool
{
     if (a.size() < b.size())
          return true;
     if (a.size() > b.size())
          return false;
     return a < b;
}
```